# GXT Drag and drop from tree label to a widget

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I just want to drag and drop an label from tree to a widget. I am using the below code and it is not getting dropped as a widget. Can you please help me how to display a widget as a dropped item.

```
 final FlowLayoutContainer dropContainer = new FlowLayoutContainer();
 dropContainer.setBorders(true);

 DropTarget target = new DropTarget(dropContainer) {
   @Override
   protected void onDragDrop(DndDropEvent event) {
     super.onDragDrop(event);
     Widget window = (Widget) event.getData();
     dropContainer.add(window);
   }
 };
 target.setGroup("test");
 target.setOverStyle("drag-ok");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating widget, you can instantiate new window like below and set the properties of it.

```
final FlowLayoutContainer dropContainer = new FlowLayoutContainer();
dropContainer.setBorders(true);

DropTarget target = new DropTarget(dropContainer) {
@Override
protected void onDragDrop(DndDropEvent event) {
     super.onDragDrop(event);
     Window window = new Window();
     window.setClosable(true);
     window.setHeight(200);
     window.setWidth(200);
};
target.setGroup("test");
target.setOverStyle("drag-ok");
}
```